# Elasticsearch - Exeption in mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I use Elasticsearch High level client 6.1 and when I try to find some logs due to required values, I get this exception:

`"reason":{"type":"exception","reason":"Elasticsearch exception [type=query_shard_exception, reason=No mapping found for [timeStamp] in order to sort on]","index_uuid":"EwqLKS3ZTDqlGdqfuHHi5w","index":".kibana"}}]},"hits":{"total":3,"max_score":null,"hits":[{"_index":"portal-logs-01.02.2018","_type":"logs_info","_id":"Vh5zUGEBAUNy8RN4gRLf","_score":null,"_source":{"timeStamp":"2018-01-31T15:30:41.000Z","header":"test Header 15","message":"test message 34","level":"TRACE","node":"first node","system":"super system 100000","port":9400,"module":"test module","submodule":"test submodule","thread":"test thread","operation":"some operation","sessionId":"1","userLogin":"user","userName":"user","office":"of 52","location":{"lat":41.12,"lon":-71.34},"ip":"192.168.3.93","device":"some device"},"sort":[1517412641000]},{"_index":"portal-logs-01.02.2018","_type":"logs_info","_id":"Vx5zUGEBAUNy8RN4hRLJ","_score":null,"_source":{"timeStamp":"2018-01-31T15:30:41.000Z","header":"test Header 15","message":"test message 34","level":"TRACE","node":"first node","system":"super system 100000","port":9400,"module":"test module","submodule":"test submodule","thread":"test thread","operation":"some operation","sessionId":"1","userLogin":"user","userName":"user","office":"of 52","location":{"lat":41.12,"lon":-71.34},"ip":"192.168.3.93","device":"some device"},"sort":[1517412641000]},{"_index":"portal-logs-01.02.2018","_type":"logs_info","_id":"VR5zUGEBAUNy8RN4fxIq","_score":null,"_source":{"timeStamp":"2018-01-31T15:30:41.000Z","header":"test Header 15","message":"test message 34","level":"TRACE","node":"first node","system":"super system 100000","port":9400,"module":"test module","submodule":"test submodule","thread":"test thread","operation":"some operation","sessionId":"1","userLogin":"user","userName":"user","office":"of 52","location":{"lat":41.12,"lon":-71.34},"ip":"192.168.3.93","device":"some device"},"sort":[1517412641000]}]}}`

This is logs from ES server:

```
[2018-02-01T02:46:51,407][DEBUG][o.e.a.s.TransportSearchAction] [node-43] [portal-user-26.01.2018][3], node[SAPKQLGGSJiR8bMBdkNvfQ], [P], s[STARTED], a[id=9d6qWfW3SWaigflL9TCmmw]: Failed to execute [SearchRequest{searchType=QUERY_THEN_FETCH, indices=[], indicesOptions=IndicesOptions[id=38, ignore_unavailable=false, allow_no_indices=true, expand_wildcards_open=true, expand_wildcards_closed=false, allow_aliases_to_multiple_indices=true, forbid_closed_indices=true, ignore_aliases=false], types=[], routing='null', preference='null', requestCache=null, scroll=null, maxConcurrentShardRequests=10, batchedReduceSize=512, preFilterShardSize=128, source={"from":0,"size":20,"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"match_phrase":{"header":{"query":"test Header 15","slop":0,"boost":1.0}}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}},"sort":[{"timeStamp":{"order":"desc"}}]}}]
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [node-70][192.168.3.70:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardException: No mapping found for [timeStamp] in order to sort on
 at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.FieldSortBuilder.build(FieldSortBuilder.java:319) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortBuilder.buildSort(SortBuilder.java:155) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:718) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:552) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:528) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:324) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$2.onResponse(SearchService.java:310) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$2.onResponse(SearchService.java:306) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$3.doRun(SearchService.java:996) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:637) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.TimedRunnable.doRun(TimedRunnable.java:41) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_162]
```

I have such mapping:
      PUT _template/portal-logs

```
 {
      "template": "portal-logs-*",
      "settings": { "number_of_shards": 5 },
      "mappings": {
          "logs_info": {
            "_all": {
              "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
              "device": {"type": "keyword"},
              "header": {"type": "text"},
              "ip": {"type": "keyword"},
              "level": {"type": "text"},
              "location": {"type": "geo_point"},
              "message": {"type": "text"},
              "module": {"type": "keyword"},
              "node": {"type": "keyword"},
              "office": {"type": "keyword"},
              "operation": {"type": "keyword"},
              "port": {"type": "integer"},
              "sessionId": {"type": "keyword"},
              "submodule": {"type": "keyword"},
              "system": {"type": "keyword"},
              "thread": {"type": "keyword"},
              "timeStamp": {"type": "date"},
              "userLogin": {"type": "keyword"},
              "userName": {"type": "keyword"}
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

and this is a part of the code:

```
sourceBuilder.query(bqb)
                    .size(pageable.getPageSize()).from(pageable.getOffset())
                    .sort(new FieldSortBuilder("timeStamp").order(SortOrder.DESC));
```

Comment: Can you show what you get when running this: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/portal-logs-01.02.2018` ?

Comment: added in answers.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the problem is that you're querying all indices, including `.kibana` which doesn't have any `timeStamp` field as the error message tells.

```
{
  "index": ".kibana",
  "index_uuid": "EwqLKS3ZTDqlGdqfuHHi5w",
  "reason": "Elasticsearch exception [type=query_shard_exception, reason=No mapping found for [timeStamp] in order to sort on]",
  "type": "exception"
}
```

You should restrain your query to the `portal-log-*` indices only, and it will work out.

Comment: SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("portal-logs-*");
That helps.
Thanks.

Comment: anything more needed to close this answer?